# Separate install per project? suiteCRM, sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Company has projects each of which have their own accounts, opportunities and contacts.

Each project is self contained. So if I'm working in project (A), I don't need to see any elements from project (B).

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Separate sugarCRM install per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are completely self-contained, and the number of projects will not change frequently then two separate instanced could indeed make sense, especially if the projects will need *different* CRM customizations and have different users. If there are users that work with both projects, you could maybe add some solution that shares the login session across both CRM instances (e.g. single sign-on) for convenience reasons. I don't know if there are good solutions for that available.

If you however decide to use a single CRM for both projects,  I only see those options:

- Use Team Security to control which record can be seen/accessed by which teams->users (a.k.a. row level security). This is a [built-in feature](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.9/Ent/Administration_Guide/Team_Management/) in commercial versions of Sugar. For SugarCRM CE and SuiteCRM there appear to be similar [3rd party plugins](https://store.suitecrm.com/support/securitysuite) available for purchase.
- Create different account/contacts/opportunity modules for the projects in ModuleBuilder. I strongly advice **against** this, especially if you use forecasts. There are tweaks, features and functionality that are programmed to only work with the default modules. Those will not work properly with such custom modules. So additional to the effort of creating those modules (and maybe keeping their customizations in sync, if they are supposed to be the same across both projects) you will also have to fix/work-around/code things that work in the default modules but not in the custom ones. If the projects are wildly different and of sufficient size to justify the extra effort, this could be worth it. Otherwise: **don't**